Electric garage door randomly sounding
I have a NEKO electric garage door. Recently I have noticed the alarm going off as if an appliance is blocking the sensor. Everytime I check it, the sensor line is clear. What else could be causing this issue? I've removed all spiders and webs

what do you mean by appliance?

Am I the only one who wants to blame the cat? :*)

Is there any indication in the alarm as to which sensor is showing the blockage?

Check the door opener sensors more closely. Watch to see if track movement momentarily moves one or both sensors out of alignment as the door is moving.
Next,
Disconnect the garage door opener momentarily. Push the door closed by hand from the top where the arm connects to the door. This can be difficult to do. As you’re pushing the door, notice if there is any resistance areas that could be causing the alarm telling you that there is an obstruction that doesn’t really appear to be there. Also pull the door open the same way and observe any snags to the door. Next look at the inside jams with the door open. Look to see if there is any worn wood areas or areas that it appears that the door is rubbing in an excessive way. This will need to be corrected to make the door move freely. The alarm can mean the door is slightly being obstructed as it’s moving down, or sensors out of alignment or sensorsmoving out of alignment as the door moves in the downward position.
There may also be a force adjustment on the up and down travel. As a last resort, you may be able to turn up the pushing or pulling force before the alarm is Tripped.
As requested, A simple checklist:
1- check the sensors closely. Make sure they’re lit solid. Try to find the center of the signal. This can be done by moving the receiving sensor around slightly with your hand to see where the strongest signal is. Then you want to tighten it as best you can. Many times the sensor is very loose and can look on Mark, but actually be very sloppy. You may actually have to lay on the floor, bring the door down with your remote control and watch the sensor to make sure that it’s staying lit solidly. Also, Absolutely make sure that these sensors are very clean.
2- disconnect the door from the garage door opener. Push the door shut from the top as though you are the garage door opener.  If the door seems to get stuck, don’t force it. Stop, walk to the door and see where the door is sticking, twirl the rollers or look to see if the door is pinching against the jams. This must be corrected. The garage door opener may be alerting to a slight jam.
3- i’m not familiar with that brand of garage door opener, but most have a down and up sensitivity adjustment. Sometimes from the factory, this adjustment is too light. Meaning that the door opener allows zero resistance Before alerting to a problem or reversing the door. Find this setting. I usually set this about Midway, or-halfway. If a 0-5 setting, I would set it about a 2 1/2 to 3. I would set it set it this way for the up and down. This is just my personal preference.

This looks like a good general-purpose door sensor diagnostic, which is fine. But please break it up into paragraphs, part maybe even a bullet list of "things to check".
